# Angularjs: $window.history.go not working in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, browser-history, ios10.2

My webapp is using angularjs-1.5.11 and we are using below line to go back in the application:

```
$window.history.go(-1)
```

This is **not working in ios 10.2.1**
I've tried the below, but didn't work

```
window.history.go(-1) 
history.back()
navigator.app.backHistory
```

I saw other posts which suggests to disable hashListening but I'm not sure how to do this in angularjs.

Anyone has suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Try do it using `jquery`

```
  $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {

      $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
      $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;

  });
```

And also make sure that your files in this order

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script> <!-- Note your script before jqm -->
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Comment: At the moment, my app is not using/having any jquery at all, so I'm little hesitant to include it. Will try it if nothing else works. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

Use the below code

```
<button type="button" onclick="goBack()">Go To Back</button>
```

Comment: what does goBack() do ?